# How to Get Host Name connected to a Socket using CFSocketNativeHandle iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Socket programming to connect devices each other in iOS. 
I want to get connected device's Host Name which is connected to a socket using CFSocketNativeHandle.

When other device connected to my Socket i get callback in following callback function:

```
static void serverAcceptCallback(CFSocketRef socket, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info) 
{
    // We can only process "connection accepted" calls here    
    if ( type != kCFSocketAcceptCallBack ) 
    {
        return;
    }

    // for an AcceptCallBack, the data parameter is a pointer to a CFSocketNativeHandle
    CFSocketNativeHandle nativeSocketHandle = *(CFSocketNativeHandle*)data;
    uint8_t name[SOCK_MAXADDRLEN];
    socklen_t namelen = sizeof(name);
    NSData *peer = nil;
    if (0 == getpeername(nativeSocketHandle, (struct sockaddr *)name, &namelen)) {
        peer = [NSData dataWithBytes:name length:namelen];
        NSString *hostName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:peer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"HostName=%@",hostName);
    }
}
```

Here I am getting NSData for "peer" but i am getting NSString *hostName=null.

How can i get exact Host name with this NSData.

Comment: you got succeed for get name of device ?

Answer (score 0):

`getpeername()` returns the address of the peer connected to the socket. You can access it using code below:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr ;
socklen_t len = sizeof(addr) ;
int res = getpeername(nativeSocketHandle, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &len) ;
if (res == 0) {
    char strAddr[20] ;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr.sin_addr, strAddr, sizeof(strAddr)) ;
    printf("ip %s\n", strAddr) ;
}
```

Comment: This gives me IP address of connected device, But i want name for that device.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing the socket knows is the IP address of the other end of the connection, so when you use `getpeername` it returns you the IP address. You will need to look up the IP address using either [`CFhost` or POSIX calls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/ResolvingDNSHostnames.html) - there are a squillion references to how to accomplish this using the POSIX APIs.

There is a very good chance that the other end will not be the same as the name of the device.